# Check reboot required for installation

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, installation

I'm developing installer and I need somehow to check system reboot after previous uninstallation. Ideally, I want to store some registry key, which will remove self after system reboot and which I can check during installation start. Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Well, why do you need to reboot? For example, if some file can't be deleted because it's in use, couldn't you just check whether the file is gone yet?

Comment: I need to reboot because of driver uninstalltion (from previous installation/uninstallation). I need to definitely know user rebooted machine after drivers remove.

Comment: @rapt0r - I probably should have asked this before posting my answer, but do you have control over the driver uninstaller or is it a third party driver?

Comment: It is third party driver, so I need manually put flag somewhere..

Comment: Are you launching their driver installer somehow? How do you expect to know when the driver has been uninstalled if you don't have any control over the uninstaller?

Comment: @rapt0r - Put another way, how would you know *when* to put the flag somewhere?

Comment: After uninstallation I have a boolean flag, which tells me reboot required (which I get from driver installer).

Comment: @rapt0r - Ok then what's the problem? When the boolean flag returned is true (or false depending on what is appropriate), create a registry value in the key referenced in by my answer. Then in your installer check to see if it exists. If the computer's been restarted then it won't exist anymore.

Comment: Who would remove this key after system restart?

Comment: @rapt0r - Windows will do it for you. See the documentation linked in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the functionality found in the [RunOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) registry key. It'll kick off a program when Windows starts and delete the registry entry for you.